# How do I set the background of UIScrollView to be transparent?

Tags: image, background, uiimageview

What i ultimately would LOVE to do is having my scroll view contents scrolling (in the scroll view control), and have a static background (a wallpaper image).

I've tried a combination of things, none of which really yields what im looking for, not even close really.

Has anybody attempted this before?

Answer (score 19):

This is actually very easy, a `UIScrollView` inherits from a `UIView` so you just need to set the `backgroundColor` property:

```
aScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

The above line of code sets the background to transparent so you can see through to whatever you want to put behind. Note also that you should do the same thing to the sub-views that you put inside the scroll-view - those views should also have a transparent background colour.

If you want a static image, use a pattern as in the line of code below. This can be a texture image smaller than the screen that will be repeated/tiled, or a full-screen image so you don't see any repeats.

```
aScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:anImage];
```

Comment: Considering how easy this technique is, I'm thinking it must be either iOS 4+ or even iOS 5+. Can anybody confirm?

Comment: The views that you put inside the scroll view also need to have a clear background colour.

Answer (score 9):

For those not having clear answer to this. It goes:

put an dummy holder imageview to the mainview and set it to the desired background image or set its backcolor as pattern, then inside this view put the scrollview and set its background to transparent.

Then you get the desired effect as with Safari on iPad for example on page scroll.

This is a code for Monotouch, but is straightforward to understand.

```
this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage (UIImage.FromFile ("Images/About-bg0.jpg"));
scrollView = new UIScrollView (new RectangleF (0, 0, 320, 450));
        scrollView.ContentSize = new SizeF (320, 640 + 508 + 1000);
        //scrollView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage (UIImage.FromFile ("Images/About-bg0.jpg"));
        scrollView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
```

Comment: self.oneColumnScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];  Works great for me! Thanks Pavel.

Answer (score 2):

After some quick googleing I found two links that will help you:

[Google Groups discussion on this question](http://groups.google.com/group/iphonesdkdevelopment/browse_thread/thread/e93f4654ff095982/ed2d07ae493ec41b?lnk=raot&pli=1)
[Blog post on how to do this.](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/picubed)

Comment: hmm. im somewhat skeptical this will work. but thanks, ill see if i find success.

Comment: Ok. so apparantly a transparent UIScrollView is certainly.
It seems like my scroll viewer's content is whats making it NOT translucent. How can i make the content (a UIView) to be transparent?

Comment: Ok. it's simply setting the content UIView's self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]. that was a long time fixing a very simple bug.

Comment: @Edward An: You should post your solution as an answer for others to find.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this,

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"content.png"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me...

```
self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tileableImage.png"]];
```